# customising the file outline for weird section labels

Tags: overleaf

I am absolutely **loving** the new file outline feature in Overleaf! It super helps me navigate and even clarify large documents like the book I'm writing. But I have another large document, an academic CV in an ancient format. The section headers there are for some reason called \sectiontitle

I'm sure there's some clever way to make an alias or something so that both I can trick overleaf into showing me my sections & letting me jump between them, AND I can keep my ancient style file happy? (FWIW it's % Copyright (c) 1987 by Stephen Gildea )

Comment: presumably you could use `\section` and put `\newcommand\section{\sectiontitle}` in the preamble but hard to say with no code shown

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle but nope, can't do that because section is already defined and does something else -- not anything that I use, but the \newcommand won't parse.

Comment: @JoannaBryson (Tom from Overleaf support here.) You can try tricking the file outline by using `\addsect` and defining `\let\addsect=\sectiontitle`. But that's basically a dirty trick that might not work and that will quite likely confuse you yourself later when you get back to the file after some time. Overall, I'm afraid this doesn't have a good solution; we're obviously not able to look for non-standard sectioning commands; `\addsect` and friends are the only ones we parse for that do not come from the basic LaTeX classes. Still I hope this helps.

Comment: @yo' thanks! not sure why it's obvious that you a) don't have a list of keywords you check and b) can't then add to that list, but I'll try your hack.

Comment: @yo' nope, that doesn't work at all.